# Ansible playbook create new directory fails

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm having this following playbook structure to load data from a yml file to the Jinja2 template and then generate a new yml file with same structure.

ansible-starter.yml

```
- name : Properties configuration - Jinja2
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
     - ../data.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Creating config directory
       file:
         path: ../j2-resources/generated
         state: directory
         mode: '0755'
     - name: Applying configuration template to data.yml
       template:
          src: ./template-files/template.yml.j2
          dest: ./generated/updated.yml
```

But it keeps giving below error :

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/j2-resources/ansible-starter.yml': line 17, column 11, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

 - name: Creating config directory
    file:
        ^ here
```

Seems like there have been some indentation issues. Make sure you to make you yml file go through a yml formatter before execution..

Comment: Check `file:` indentation. There is one extra leading whitespace.

Comment: Checked. That wasnt the case

Comment: Did the error change?

Comment: No. still the same error. checked with ansible.builtin.file: too. Doest work

Comment: I found the error. Line `- name: Applying configuration...` is bad indented. There is one extra leading whitespace.

Comment: Couldnt be. it works fine without the `Creating config directory` task

Comment: Yes, but YAML indentation is relative to other items in an array. If you have two tasks, the indentation must be respected between each other.

Comment: Your playbook does not respect yaml and/or ansible syntax. Please [take Y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) and pay attention to indentation and new lines. You should also read through the [Intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#about-playbooks) to learn the basic concepts and syntax. You can validate your playbooks with [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/) prior to posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of indentation mistakes:

It should be:

```
- name: Properties configuration - Jinja2
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
     - ../data.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Creating config directory
      file:
         path: ../j2-resources/generated
         state: directory
         mode: '0755'
    - name: Applying configuration template to data.yml
      template:
         src: ./template-files/template.yml.j2
         dest: ./generated/updated.yml
```